# Capture Data State on Error at runtime - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling

I have a question regarding error handling practices within `SQL Server`.

What I would like to accomplish is easy error re-creation. I have a very active SQL Server installation with constantly changing data in the tables I am interested in. It is modeling an active warehouse environment.

I've already built a generic error handler for all the stored procedures on this installation in order to track errors and log specifics about the cause of the error such as:

- calling line (this gives the `EXEC` statement of the stored procedure as well as input variables)
- error_message
- error_state
- error_number
- error_line
- etc.

What I am missing is reproducibility. Even if I were to run the same statement just a few minutes after being notified that an error occurred, I cannot be sure that my results would be the same due to the underlying data changing.

I would like to capture the state of the data on the database when the error occurred.

This could be something like a database image that I could then import into a clean SQL Server installation and execute the erring line in order to perfectly capture what was happening on the database the moment the error occurred.

Due to the nature of needing to capture this at runtime, I would prefer a light-weight solution. Perhaps only capturing the tables relevant to the failing statement.

Does anyone know if this is possible or has been done before? It is really only critical to try and suss out logical errors. It wouldn't be necessary for something like a deadlock.

I would ultimately turn these data subsets into `XML` or `JSON` and include them in the error log when appropriate.

Comment: There isn't really any solution for this, every command will be doing different things. You could restore a log backup if you have them, but that could take some time. To be honest, XEvents is probably better placed for a lot of this stuff

Comment: You can try to create database snapshot at that instance. initially, it will be empty sparse file, which will grow, when source database changes. But, take care, with more errors, you might get more snapshots and difficult to manage. you can delete snapshot once you are done with your analysis.

Comment: Possible idea, haven't tried it... If you're able to catpure the LSN at the time of the error you could restore transaction log backups [to a specific LSN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recover-to-a-log-sequence-number-sql-server#examples).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I see, so the idea would be to use a regular .bak file of PROD but restore it to the LSN point to run tests. This might actually work. There would be a lag time for catching errors, but I believe we are backing up the PROD db every 12 hours or so. Do you know how I would capture the LSN at upon encountering an error?